# check for value in csv file then print line with awk / sed

Tags: awk, sed

Is it possible to parse a .csv file and look for the 13th entry containing a particular value.

So data for example would be

```
10,1,a,bhd,5,7,10,,,8,9,3,19,0
```

I only want to extract lines which have a value of 3 in the 13th field if that makes sense.

Tried it wish a bash while loop using cut etc but was messy.

Not sure if there a awk / sed method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is beginner level awk.

```
awk -F, '$13==3' file
```

`-F,` is for setting field separator to comma, `$13` is the 13th field's value. For each line, if `$13==3` evaluates true the line is printed.

Comment: My god how did i never think of field seperators. Thansk fot my moment of madness